# SQL return the largest value (smaller than the existing value) in the list

Tags: sql, sql-server

The object is to find the largest value smaller than existing one in the list, say:

- ID | Input | Output
- ID | ColA  | ColB
- A  | 1     | NULL
- B  | 2     | 1
- C  | 7     | 4
- D  | 4     | 2

My existing code work but is very slow at large dataset: 
(order of complexity is NlogN, hopefully the solution should have order of complexity of N or lower. I tried cte by still slow.)

```
SELECT TMain.Id, TMain.ColA As Input, T1.ColA As Output, 
FROM TABLEA As TMain
LEFT JOIN TABLEA T1 
    ON  T1.Id = TMain.Id
    AND T1.ColA = (SELECT Min (T2.ColA)
        FROM TABLEA T2
        WHERE T2.Id = T1.Id
        AND T2.ColA > TMain.ColA)
```

Comment: For performance related questions it's very beneficial to include the actual execution plan.  This is a great tool to use for doing so: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: share the given input sample and output sample as well

Answer (score 1):

Use `lag()`.  Your code is hard to follow, but I think you want:

```
select a.*, lag(input) over (partition by id order by input)
from tablea:
```

Comment: Yes, the lag function is everything I need.